# SVG to image conversion firefox, safari not support But Chrome working correct

Tags: svg, image-conversion

I am working SVG image after come customize I will convert SVG to PNG using Image() function, Chrome browser is working correctly, But safari and firefox is not working, My code is given below,

```
<pre>

$('#next').click( function(){

var image = new Image();
var xml = '<?php echo str_replace(PHP_EOL,'',$_SESSION['tshirt']); ?>';
image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + escape(xml); 
document.getElementById('output').appendChild(image);
image.onload = function() {
    image.onload = function() {};
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
}  

});
</pre>
```

This is my custom page
[image]

This is my firefox window

I am not getting out put [image]

This is my chrome window 
[image]

Comment: Does the image have height and width attributes that are not percentages?

Comment: SVG tag like <SVG ......></SVG>

Comment: Sorry I am not understand... Please explain, How to convert SVG to PNG???

Comment: Please add the SVG you are trying to convert to the question.

Comment: Please give me your main id I will send, because here not type above 3000 character so please give me your email id

Comment: <svg xml:space="preserve" enable-background="new 0 0 500 275" viewBox="0 0 500 275" y="0px" x="0px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1" version="1.1">
<path d="M369.6,241.2c4.8-0.2,10-0.3,14.8-0.5c4.8-0.1,9.2-0.2,12.5-0.3
 l0.6,0c12.2-0.1,22-0.2,26-2.5c3.8-2.2,4.3-4,4.4-4.2c0-0.2,0-1.9-0.5-3.7c-0.3-1-0.3-4.3-0.3-7.8c0-3.6,0-7.5-0.3-9.8
 c-0.2-2-0.5-6.6-0.8-11.5c-0.3-6.4-0.6-13.2-0.6-15c0-1.2-0.1-8-0.3-16.8c-0.3-17.1-0.8-41.4-0.7-44.7c0.1-3,0.9-9.8,1.6-15.1
 c0.4-3.5,0.8-6.3,0.8-7c0-1.6,1-3.4,1.3-3.9c-1.8-4.8-2.8-9.6-3.8-14.5c-3.3-

Comment: See my first comment then i.e. the `<svg>` element needs width and height attributes which are not percentages.

Comment: Ok, But I am getting the image from chrome browser, When I run webpage in firefox, or safari, This is not working.....

Comment: Which is why I'm explaning how to get it working.

Comment: Now I set width & height, It was worked correctly, Thank you so much, But now I include image inside SVG, this image is not showing, Now what can I do?

Comment: set them when you process it then i.e. after the ar xml =... line, update the xml to have width/height.

Comment: Yes I have set width and height, <svg><image class="text" id="logo1" xlink:href="<?php echo ($_SESSION['logo1'] != '') ? '../tshirt/files/'.$_SESSION['logo1'] : '../tshirt/img/logo.png'  ?>" src="<?php echo ($_SESSION['logo1'] != '') ? '../tshirt/files/'.$_SESSION['logo1'] : '../tshirt/img/logo.png'  ?>" x="93" y="55" height="25" width="25" />
<image class="text" id="logo2" xlink:href="../tshirt/img/logo.png" src="../tshirt/img/logo.png" x="150" y="55" height="25" width="25" /> 
</svg>

Comment: This is my image tag inside svg, this is not show when i will capture the screen